# Dcount on multiselect listbox?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

Me again. This code works fine when only 1 item is selected, however when more than one item is selected I get the error "syntax error (comma) in query expression" on the following line of code: 
    intCountNull = DCount("*", "Scrubbed", strCriteria & " Is Null")

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Command29_Click()
Dim strCriteria As String
Dim intCountNull As Integer
Dim varItem As Variant

'On Error GoTo Err_Command29_Click

Me.Fields_Values.RowSource = ""

For Each varItem In Me!List101.ItemsSelected
strCriteria = strCriteria & "," & Me!List101.ItemData(varItem)
Next varItem

strCriteria = Right(strCriteria, Len(strCriteria) - 1)

intCountNull = DCount("*", "Scrubbed", strCriteria & " Is Null")
Fields_Values.RowSource = intCountNull & " null values found in " & strCriteria

Exit_Command29_Click:
    Exit Sub
'Err_Command29_Click:
    'MsgBox "Please select a field"
```

End Sub

Comment: What do you want? AND for each criterion or OR for each? Or even separate counts? You should write out strCriteria and adjust your code to give the line you need.

Comment: I need separate lines and separate counts for each item selected.

Comment: So how do you see this `Fields_Values.RowSource` working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*... when more than one item is selected I get the error "syntax error (comma) in query expression" on the following line of code: `intCountNull = DCount("*", "Scrubbed", strCriteria & " Is Null")`*

That makes sense.  If the list box selections were "field1", "field3", and "field4", your `DCount()` would throw error #3075, "*Syntax error (comma) in query expression 'field1,field3,field4 Is Null'.*"

The `DCount()` expression would be evaluated like this SELECT statement:

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM Scrubbed
WHERE field1,field3,field4 Is Null
```

And the db engine will definitely complain about that `WHERE` clause.  You can't give it a list of field names and ask it whether the list `Is Null`.  You would have to separately ask whether each field `Is Null`.

That is the explanation for why you get that error.  However, I think you need to change your approach.

Build up the `RowSource` value list string for `Fields_Values` as you iterate through `List101` selected items.  (Make sure you have Value List as the Row Source Type property for `Fields_Values`.)  Here is a tested sample which does what I think you want.

```
Private Sub Command29_Click()
    Dim strCriteria As String
    Dim intCountNull As Integer
    Dim varItem As Variant
    Dim strRowSource As String

    Me.Fields_Values.RowSource = ""
    For Each varItem In Me!List101.ItemsSelected
        strCriteria = "[" & Me!List101.ItemData(varItem) & _
            "] Is Null"
        intCountNull = DCount("*", "Scrubbed", strCriteria)
        'Debug.Print strCriteria, intCountNull '
        strRowSource = strRowSource & ";" & intCountNull & _
            " null values found in " & _
            Me!List101.ItemData(varItem)
    Next varItem

    'Debug.Print strRowSource '
    If Len(strRowSource) > 0 Then
        strRowSource = Mid(strRowSource, 2)
        Me.Fields_Values.RowSource = strRowSource
    End If
    'Debug.Print strRowSource '
End Sub
```

Also I don't see why the user should even be allowed to click `Command29` unless `List101` contains selected items.  So consider disabling `Command29` until selections have been made.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.Command29.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub List101_AfterUpdate()
    Me.Command29.Enabled = (Me.List101.ItemsSelected.Count > 0)
End Sub
```

Finally, I'll suggest you do yourself a favor by giving your controls meaningful names ...  `Command29` could be `cmdShowNullCounts` and `List101` could be `lstFieldNames`.  Meaningful names are especially helpful when you're dealing with dozens of controls.  You should also find them helpful when you need to revisit the form design after a few months.  Anyone else who has to take over in the future will appreciate your courtesy.

Comment: You will need to set the RowSourceType, I reckon.

Comment: This code from HansUp worked perfectly. Thank you for your help.